# RSA encryption from NodeJs Server and Decryption in Flutter App

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, cryptography, rsa

I want to encrypt data from NodeJs Server and Decrypt it in my Flutter App.
Currently, I am using [node-rsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa) in my NodeJs App.

I have tried several packages from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/), but none can successfully decrypt the data.

Can someone suggest a better way.

Server Side Code (NodeJS) :

```
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
const text = 'Hello RSA!';
const encrypted = key.encrypt(text, 'base64');
console.log('encrypted: ', encrypted);
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason HTTPS/TLS/SSL is insufficient or won't work for your needs? That would certainly be simpler, and less prone to implementation error. In any case, [pointycastle](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle) is likely your best bet in Dart.

Comment: you sure you setup `key` correctly?

Comment: Tried pointycastle but it did'nt work in my case. @chuck-batson

Comment: Yes, key setup are correct @Qori